# How to SSH (or remotely connect) into to the Pi 3 though its own Wi-fi?

Tags: wifi, ssh, wireless, remote

The WiFi access is set up in my Pi 3-B using `hostapd` as shown in [this link](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/). I'm able to connect to it through WiFi, but don't know how to SSH into it.

Previously, it was possible to connect to it over SSH through a common WiFi network by using its allotted `wlan0` IP, but as I made it into an AP, I am not able to do that.

Is there any way to SSH (or any mode of remote access) to the Pi in which you are connected as an AP-client?

Comment: What happens when you try to connect to the Raspberry Pi's IP? Do you reach the login screen or does the connection timeout before that?
Also check your firewall/iptables rules. Make sure port 22 is open.

Comment: Thanks for trying, @AbdulMueid. But the problem is solved now. It happens to be the problem with the DHCP connection setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! The problem was with the DHCP setup. After following [this post](http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot), I was able to connect to it by specifying the static IP address specified to the `wlan0`.

The method uses `udhcpd` package for DHCP management (not sure as to why `dnsmasq` never worked for me).

The static address was specified in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file like so

```
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.43.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Hence it was possible to access it through the client system (which was connected to it using the Pi-3's own in-built WiFi) using this IP address

```
$ ssh pi@192.168.43.2
pi@192.168.43.2's password: 

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Sun Jul 31 15:21:56 2016 from 192.168.42.20
pi@raspberry:~ $
```

I am also able to do this even without the Ethernet connected.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with configurations, install RPi-Wireless-Hotspot and it will did all for you, dhcp, dns, etc. I was messing configuring dhcp, dnsmasq, interfaces, bridges and can't put it in production, and with this in 5 minutes you have it working very well.

Comment: What is RPi-Wireless-Hotspot?